# 'ia32-libs is not installed' while installing Skype on Ubuntu

Tags: skype

I downloaded skype from official site, but when installing I get this type of error

```
(Reading database ... 100%
(Reading database ... 150271 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking skype (from .../skype-ubuntu_4.0.0.8-1_amd64.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype:
 skype depends on ia32-libs; however:
  Package ia32-libs is not installed.

dpkg: error processing skype (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
```

Read about that I need to install ia32-libs. Tried to install them like this

```
sudo apt-get install package-name:i386
```

But it doesn't find it. Any hint? Thx.

Comment: Install ia32-libs with `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`?

Comment: Yes, just tested it. The terminal says that `Some packeges cannot be installed` and then `ia32-libs : Depends: ia32-libs-multiarch but it cannot be installed.
E: Cannot repair errors, you have held packets.
`

Comment: Check the solutions on this post and let us know how it worked out http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Comment: Hi @BrunoPereira sorry, just had time to try all the solitions written there and IT seems neither of them worked. Also the Update Manager can't read the installed(?) package of skype and gives an error

Comment: I've rolled back to 12.04 and it installed there without troubles.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -f
```

This should fix package problems